# Image and js is not geting displayed from apache tomcat

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, tomcat

I have facing strange problem. I have deployed images and js file in Apache Tomcat directrory but it is not showing on page and a warning is coming up:

> Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8084/webApp/img/access.jpg".

Earlier it was working fine but now jquery is also not working and the following error is coming up:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Earlier this error message was appearing in Firefox but Chrome was working fine. But now it is showing the error in Chrome as well.

I have also tried to use the absolute path but no success.

```html
<script src="/webApp/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://localhost:8084/webApp/img/access.jpg"/>
```

Comment: try to access your resource through the address bar to see it is available or not (localhost:8084/webapp/img/access.jpg). If not, then check whether the image is there or whether it is corrupted. I had a problem with resized image once, it can load on some browser, but not on the others

Comment: image is present over there it is not accesssible through address bar also but image is present over there and it is getting opened

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tomcat, you should locate the resources at $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT folder. From there, you might have access to the files.
You can check the access permissions from terminal. If you use unix / linux, locate to the folder:

```
cd $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT
```

And execute the command:

```
ls -la
```

This means it can be accessed by everyone, so should be available to everyone accessing to the server by browser

```
drwxr-x**r-x@** 22 user  staff    704 11 jun 01:25 .
```

You could also try changing the permisions, but your server would be unsure:

```
sudo chmod a+rx webApp/img/access.jpg
```

Or go to the webApp folder via cd and execute

```
sudo chmod -R a+rx .
```

Deppending on your preferences (the last one means giving permission to all resources on webApp folder, what means givving access to all your projects in server, quite unsure...).
Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: In the third code block, pay attention to the end of the third column
drwxr-xr-x@
The r-x@ means that every body can read and execute the current folder, because at the end there's a dot (.).